# Trying to find the input for crc16 ibm?

Tags: python, crc16

I am trying to write a code for crc16 in python but i am not getting correct remainder. I send hex_string as input
and also try for byte array and binary but still not getting proper output.what should be the input ??

```py
import sys
import time
class CRC:

    def crc16ibm(msg1):
        #msg11=hex(msg1)
        msg11 = list(msg1)
        buflen = len(msg1)
        print("The message is ZZZ : ", msg1)
        #print("Hex value : " + hex(msg1))
        print("The length is QQQ : ", len(msg1))
        preset, offset, polynom =0, 0,0xA001

        preset = preset & 0xFFFF
        polynom = polynom & 0xFFFF
        buflen_i: int = buflen
        code_move = 0xFFFF
        crc = preset
        for i in range(buflen):
            #data = msg11[(i+offset)% buflen_i] & code_move
            data = (msg1[(i+offset)% buflen_i]) & code_move
            #print(type(data))
            crc ^= data

            for j in range(8):
                if((crc & 0x0001) !=0):
                    crc = (crc>>1)^polynom
                else:
                    crc = crc>>1
        return crc&0xFFFF


    # Test data for the crc to run
    print("First set of data : ")
    #msg1 = 0x000000000000003608010000016B40D8EA30010000000000000000000000000000000105021503010101425E0F01F10000601A014E0000000000000000010000C7CF
    #crc1 = 0x0000C7CF


    msg1 = 0x000000000000004A8E010000016B412CEE000100000000000000000000000000000000010005000100010100010011001D00010010015E2C880002000B000000003544C87A000E000000001DD7E06A00000100002994
    crc1 = 0x00002994
    #msg1 = 0x000000000000008c08010000013feb55ff74000f0ea850209a690000940000120000001e09010002000300040016014703f0001504c8000c0900730a00460b00501300464306d7440000b5000bb60007422e9f180000cd0386ce000107c700000000f10000601a46000001344800000bb84900000bb84a00000bb84c00000000024e0000000000000000cf00000000000000000100003fca
    #msg1 = 0xFFFF
    #crc1 = 0xFFFF

    print("The hex message is : " + hex(msg1))
    print("The length of hex msg is :", len(hex(msg1)))
    print("The CRC is ", hex(crc1))
    print(" and lenght is ", len(hex(crc1)))

    zero, m1, kind =0, len(hex(msg1)), 'b'
    msg_a = f'{msg1:{zero}>{m1}{kind}}'
    #print(type(msg_a))

    msgInBin =bin(int(msg_a, 16)).zfill(8)
    crcchecksum = crc16ibm(msgInBin)

    print(" the msg_a is PPP : ", msg_a)
    print(" The lenght of EEE: ", len(msg_a))
    if (crcchecksum == crc1):
        print("Checksum is saying the whole package is received")
    else:
        print("The ", hex(crc1), " is not matching is ",  hex(crcchecksum))
```

Comment: You must add details to your post and not just post you code.

Comment: I already mention the details in block.Can you please clarify which details you want?

Answer (score 3):

1. The input would normally be bytes, which your examples suggest would be converted from hexadecimal to bytes.
2. Writing that hexadecimal input as a giant integer is not what you want to do. That throws away, for example, all of the leading zeros which appear to be part of the message. Your attempt to then use `list()` to get bytes out of that doesn't work. What you want is a character string of hexadecimal input, and to use `bytearray.fromhex()` to convert that to bytes.
3. Your examples have the CRC at the end. It would appear that you need to calculate the CRC on the bytes that precede the CRC, not including the CRC. You would then compare that to the CRC. (Those CRC bytes are not appended in the correct order to be able to compute the CRC on the entire message and expect to get zero.)

Where are your examples from? Can you link to the source?

Here is an example for your CRC parameters (known as CRC-16/ARC). `msg` should be a bytearray:

```
def crc16arc(msg):
    crc = 0
    for b in msg:
        crc ^= b
        for _ in range(8):
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ 0xa001 if crc & 1 else crc >> 1
    return crc

print(hex(crc16arc(b'123456789')))
print(hex(crc16arc(bytearray.fromhex("313233343536373839"))))
print(hex(crc16arc(bytearray.fromhex("3132333435363738393dbb"))))
```